# Lumen routes not working

Tags: laravel, lumen

Basically any route I try to create throws me

> 404 Not Found
>   The requested resource '/some-route' was not found on this server.

But when I leave web.php like this

```
<?php
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});
```

I can run the default route but if I add any other route this route stops working too.

I am trying to add this route, Controller should echo something but it does not reach controller.

```
$app->get('/cors', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorsController@index');
```

I tried defining the route with path to controller and without still same thing.
.htacess file is default

My .conf file is like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/lumen-projects/test/public" 
ServerName localhost             

<Directory "/var/www/html/lumen-projects/test/public"> 
    # Ignore the .htaccess file in this directory
    AllowOverride None

    # Make pretty URLs
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you enabled the Apache url rewrite module?

Comment: does `yourdomain.com/index.php/route_name` work?

Comment: Maybe you need use `$router->get('/cors', 'App\Http\Controllers\CorsController@index');`

Comment: @SapneshNaik Nope that does not work. I added my .conf file to post.

Comment: @yrv16 I have tried that, did not work.

Comment: What is lumen version you are using?

Comment: Version: `"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.6.*",`
Okay now it works with `$router->get` instead of `$app` but why could `$app` routes not work?

Comment: You can not use `$app` and `$router` togather. Try for both routes `$app` or `$router`

Comment: I am Getting http 500 error when I changed routes to `$app`.

Comment: But if you use `$router` for both routes you get `404 Not Found The requested resource '/some-route' was not found on this server.` error?

Comment: @yrv16 Nope now it works with `$router` for both routes.

Comment: ok, have you used this `/some-route` before and then removed it?

Comment: @yrv16 Maybe not sure but it did not work since the beginning because after I use `lumen new test` I tried adding route and got that error.

Comment: So if it works then ok :)